# VS Code and Yarn PnP

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v3

Are there any incompatibilities with the yarn pnp sdk and typescript?  I've installed the sdk via `yarn sdks` and in the TS Server logs it appears to be pulling from the cache (ex:)

```
/osi/disp/vob/web/.yarn/cache/typescript-patch-04b86b0e5c-24a439e062.zip/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
```

Yet VS Code cannot find modules:

```
Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

It builds and runs via webpack.  This appears to be a VS Code/sdk artifact.

Trying to trace react resolution there are some odd notes:

```
Info 1216 [08:36:07.761] DirectoryWatcher:: Added:: WatchInfo: /osi/disp/vob/web/react 1 undefined Project: /osi/disp/vob/web/tsconfig.json WatchType: Failed Lookup Locations
Info 1217 [08:36:07.761] Elapsed:: 0.06486300379037857ms DirectoryWatcher:: Added:: WatchInfo: /osi/disp/vob/web/react 1 undefined Project: /osi/disp/vob/web/tsconfig.json WatchType: Failed Lookup Locations
```

Those folders don't exist, and it seems like it may be interpreting `'react'` as `'./react'`

tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
     "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2016",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Simple repro:
https://github.com/rcketscientist/vs-code-pnp-test

Appreciate any insight or pointers to investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK is currently incompatible with TS 4.5:

https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/3722

Downgrading to 4.4.4 fixes it:

1. yarn remove typescript
2. rm -rf .yarn/sdks/typescript
3. yarn add -D typescript@4.4.4
4. yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks base